# Open PowerShell terminal in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, powershell

In Eclipse I need to run awsokta that is setup using PowerShell terminal. Is there a way to open PowerShell terminal in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

To open terminal you first use Ctrl + alt +t. After the terminal is open enter command powershell. This will open “powershell” terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Adding PowerShell to eclipse terminal selection:

Go to Windows -> Preferences. search for terminal
under local terminal click add and select PowerShell exec from your system.
[image]

To view the terminal view go to Window -> show view -> other -> terminal
[image]

by clicking one or buttons you can either open a new terminal window or switch to any terminal for the dropdown terminals selection.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add a shortcut?

Comment: as answered by @Zeus above you can use "Ctrl + alt +t".

Comment: thx. that is what I am already doing. A shortcut to the powershell directly does not seem possible.
Pressing CTRL+ALT+T and explicitly typing `powershell` has the advantage that you are immediately in the correct path. With your method you always start in the workspace root.